# StoreEval Command is not available in Selenium IDE 3.5.8

Tags: automated-testing

StoreEval is not available in Selenium IDE 3.5.8. Is there any other alternative command is there. Can anyone help..

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936843/alternate-to-storeeval-command-in-selenium-ide-3-2-3-chrome-plugin

Answer (score 3):

StoreEval has been replaced by the [execute-script](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#execute-script) command:

> version 3.1.0 (released June 21, 2018) has added support for "execute
>   script" command which is, more-or-less, a replacement of "storeEval".
>   For example, you could use something like the below to return "year"
>   variable (to be used later as ${year}):
>
> **Command**: execute script
>
> **Target**: z = new Date(); var x = z.getYear(); var y = x + 1900; return y
>
> **Value**: year
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/234
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/138

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

But am getting the below error:

executeScript on z = new Date(); var x = z.getYear(); var y = x + 1900; return y with value year Failed:
_win is null.

ExecuteScript,Storetext commands are not working.getting win null error.Could you please help on this.

Comment: @swathi Sounds like a new question and needs a lot more details. But _win is null sounds like it can't find the window or something. Also I am not sure Selenium IDE is the way to go, it is not a product for production testing. For me is it more a proof of concept and a quick way to play around with Selenium.